# Sort dictionary in Python by items inside list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to sort this kind of dictionaries:

1. First by rank
2. If rank is the same then sort by first element in other_ranks list
3. If first element in other_ranks is the same - go deeper until last element in list.

If this is a trouble, I can make this dictionary structurized in different way.

```
{'rank': 6, 'other_ranks': [7, 5]}
{'rank': 1, 'other_ranks': [7, 11, 6, 2]}
{'rank': 0, 'other_ranks': [12]}
{'rank': 1, 'other_ranks': [13, 11, 4, 3]}
{'rank': 1, 'other_ranks': [14, 12, 6, 5]}
{'rank': 4, 'other_ranks': [5, 4, 3, 2]}
{'rank': 0, 'other_ranks': [12]}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming a list, you can use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) in conjunction with the key argument of [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
from operator import itemgetter

lst = [{'rank': 6, 'other_ranks': [7, 5]},
       {'rank': 1, 'other_ranks': [7, 11, 6, 2]},
       {'rank': 0, 'other_ranks': [12]},
       {'rank': 1, 'other_ranks': [13, 11, 4, 3]},
       {'rank': 1, 'other_ranks': [14, 12, 6, 5]},
       {'rank': 4, 'other_ranks': [5, 4, 3, 2]},
       {'rank': 0, 'other_ranks': [12]}]


res = sorted(lst, key=itemgetter("rank", "other_ranks"))
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[{'other_ranks': [12], 'rank': 0},
 {'other_ranks': [12], 'rank': 0},
 {'other_ranks': [7, 11, 6, 2], 'rank': 1},
 {'other_ranks': [13, 11, 4, 3], 'rank': 1},
 {'other_ranks': [14, 12, 6, 5], 'rank': 1},
 {'other_ranks': [5, 4, 3, 2], 'rank': 4},
 {'other_ranks': [7, 5], 'rank': 6}]
```

The key here is that list and tuples are compared lexicographically, from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations):

> Sequences of the same type also support comparisons. In particular,
> tuples and lists are compared lexicographically by comparing
> corresponding elements.

Therefore just compare them as is.

Answer (score 2):

That's called lexigraphical comparison. Python's tuples implement that.

```py
dictionaries = [
    {'rank': 6, 'other_ranks': [7, 5]},
    {'rank': 1, 'other_ranks': [7, 11, 6, 2]},
    {'rank': 0, 'other_ranks': [12]},
    {'rank': 1, 'other_ranks': [13, 11, 4, 3]},
    {'rank': 1, 'other_ranks': [14, 12, 6, 5]},
    {'rank': 4, 'other_ranks': [5, 4, 3, 2]},
    {'rank': 0, 'other_ranks': [12]},
]
dictionaries.sort(key=lambda dict_: (dict_['rank'], ) + tuple(dict_['other_ranks']))
```